# Workaround for SoundCloud and its lack of client ids

Tags: api, sdk, soundcloud

my company hosts a lot of audio on SoundCloud.  We never had a client id. Now we want to start collecting data but I can't use the SDK without that id which, of course, SoundCloud stopped giving out over a year ago (and has not done anything to offer alternatives).  Does anyone have any experience with, or a workaround for, this?

Answer (score 1):

Had roughly the same problem.
You could use your browsers client_id to query the API.
Just navigate to a track page in a Browser, hit F12, open the Networking tab and click play. Look out for requests containing a client_id and copy that.
I did this a while ago (3-4 Months), and they're still working.

Con: You can't access OAuth and private stuff, just public content.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I think this will probable work for me.  I'm kind of a noob though - can I get you to give me an example?  I was able to find the client ID but cannot get it to work using the instructions on soundCloud's site...  Thanks!

Comment: @joellis13 I'm running into the same issue. I get my Client ID from the Network tab, but it returns me a 403 (Forbidden) when using it. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Maybe you are using api methods that are meant to be used with a OAuth token. I use SoundCloud in C# with a premade package after struggling with it myself. There you only have to supply the client_id and a OAuth token, which you can get from logging into soundcloud in your browser and searching the cookies for oauth_token.